# Does Prometheus expose the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler's “Current CPU Utilization” as shown in the Kubernetes dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

In the Kubernetes dashboard, I can see for a HPA the following information:

```
Min Replicas:
3
Max Replicas:
11
Target CPU Utilization:
80%
Status
Current Replicas:
3
Desired Replicas:
3
Current CPU Utilization:
10%
Last Scaled:
5 days
```

However, I can't figure out how the 10% CPU utilization is calculated?

And if this value exposed via Prometheus?

Comment: I also asked this question on devops stackexchange: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/6244/does-prometheus-expose-the-horizontal-pod-autoscalers-current-cpu-utilization

Answer (score 0):

Current CPU utilization is relative to a target.  So in your case, for example, if its 10% above the target of 80%, then it would trigger an autoscaling event.

Comment: Are you sure? I assumed in my example, the current cpu usage is 10% and if it goes over 80% this will trigger the auto scaler. Do you have a link to documentation supporting your answer?